# NodeJS in Ubuntu won't print console.log() to the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, console.log, nightmare

I am a new to programming and I am trying to follow a tutorial to scrape Craigslist and get the information from there and then print it to console/then file. 
console.log() worked in Windows 10 with NodeJS but it won't work in Ubuntu somehow. I have seen people using functions to print it, but I could not figure out how I would do it in my little project.

Here is my file contents:

```
let jquery = require('jquery')
let Nightmare = require('nightmare'),
    nightmare = Nightmare()


nightmare.goto('https://vancouver.craigslist.org/search/jjj?postedToday=1')


    .wait(3000)


    .evaluate(function() {
        let items = [];
        $('.result-title').each(function() {
            item = {}
            item["title"] = $(this).text()
            item["link"] = $(this).attr("href")
            items.push(item)
        })
        return items
    })
    .end()

    .then(function(items) {

        for (item in items) {
            console.log(items[item].title)
            console.log(items[item].link)
            console.log("\n")
        }
    });
```

Can someone help please? Thanks

Comment: Ist that supposed to log to browser console and note the ubuntu terminal

Comment: @ZadikiHassanOchola how do I print it to terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If you `console.log` anything right at the top of the script, do you see anything on the terminal?

For example:

```js
console.log('foobar') // add this line

let jquery = require('jquery')
// etc
```

If you do, try `console.log(items)` inside your final `.then` callback. Do you see anything there?

Also, you probably want to replace the `for items in item` with an `items.forEach` loop.

```js
    items.forEach(item => {
      console.log(item.title);
      console.log(item.link);
      console.log("\n");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sajad. It shows me 'foobar' if I try it outside my .then callback, it won't work in the callback function, and neither does the second improvement.